# Create matrix of comparison results using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have pandas DataFrame with the test results as following:

```
  service_name   result_1   result_2   result_3         
  service_1      2.17       100.41     0.4         
  service_2      1.11       131.41     0.45        
  service_3      4.12       234.41     0.51
```

My goal is to create another pandas DataFrame with comparison results per each test indicator and total mark, taking into consideration, that for some results the higher value, the worse mark

```
  service_name   mark_1    mark_2      mark_3(the lower value is better score)   total_mark        
  service_1      2         3           1                                         2
  service_2      3         2           2                                         3
  service_3      1         1           3                                         1
```

I suppose I could do a row by row and column by column comparison with creating bunch of intermediate DataFrames, but is there an easier way?

Comment: How is `total_mark` computed?

Comment: Also, how to mark ties (equal scores)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. Ties are marked by their average rank (e.g. score `9 > 9 > 7 > 6 >...` will be ranked as `1.5, 1.5, 3, 4,...`. This can be changed within `df.rank(method="...")` (see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)).
2. Smaller sum of `mark_N` get a lower `total_mark`.

Code:

```
# the output dataframe
out=df[["service_name"]].copy()
# individual marks
out["mark_1"] = df["result_1"].rank()
out["mark_2"] = df["result_2"].rank()
out["mark_3"] = df["result_3"].rank(ascending=False)
# total mark
out["total_mark"] = out[["mark_1", "mark_2", "mark_3"]].sum(axis=1)
out["total_mark"] = out["total_mark"].rank(ascending=False)
```

Result:

```
print(out)

  service_name  mark_1  mark_2  mark_3  total_mark
0    service_1     2.0     1.0     3.0         2.0
1    service_2     1.0     2.0     2.0         3.0
2    service_3     3.0     3.0     1.0         1.0
```

Comment: yeah, it's exactly what I need. Much appreciated.